# C# HttpWebRequest - can't resolve this request: "The client adds a MD5 hash to the X-OriginalHash HTTP header"

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, md5

I need to send json data and receive response to/from a web server. I can communicate with the webserver, it gives me responses about the json (what to correct). At one moment it gives me the following error message:

Hash information not matching the message signature.

About this message, the documentation (sent by the owners of that webserver) says the following:

=====================================

The Repository system will verify the message checksum to ensure that the data was not tampered with between parts of the whole Repository system. Messages where the hash is not valid shall not be accepted. 
This integrity check ensures that the messages making up traffic cannot be altered in transit or within the parts of the Repository system, neither can messages be added or removed from the sequence, without detection. 
The client adds a MD5 hash to the X-OriginalHash HTTP header.

This structure is then added to the message

**Message Header**

| X-OriginalHash |  1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |

| Content-Type   |  application/json |

| Authorization  |  < Token > |

=====================================

So, it says that I should add an MD5 hash to that HTTP header. But I can’t fiind the solution to this.

My code is as follows:

==========================================================

```
private void sendDataToWebserver()
{
    token = myFunctionToGetOauthToken();
    byte[] byteBodyProd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestTextBox.Text);

    HttpWebRequest bearerReqProd = WebRequest.Create("https://webserver.com") as HttpWebRequest;
    bearerReqProd.Method = "POST";
    bearerReqProd.PreAuthenticate = true;
    bearerReqProd.ContentType = "application/json";
    bearerReqProd.ContentLength = byteBodyProd.Length;
    bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");

    bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(requestTextBox.Text));

    Stream newStreamProd = bearerReqProd.GetRequestStream();
    newStreamProd.Write(byteBodyProd, 0, byteBodyProd.Length);

    WebResponse bearerRespProd = null;
    try

        bearerRespProd = bearerReqProd.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException webErr)
    {
        string response;

        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(webErr.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            statusText.Text += "\r\n" + "responseProd=" + response.ToString();
        }

        statusText.Text += "\r\n" + "Eroare WebException(Prod): " + webErr.Message;
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        statusText.Text += "\r\n" + "Eroare Exception(Prod): " + err.Message;
        return;
    }

    var responseProd = "";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(bearerRespProd.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        responseProd = reader.ReadToEnd();
        statusText.Text += "\r\n" + "responseProd=" + responseProd.ToString();
    }
}

   private string CreateMD5(string input)
    {
        // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            //byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

==========================================================

The data to be sent is in the requestTextBox.Text and an example is :

{"ID1": "EO144IB3002",

"ID2": "FACILIB300",

"Event_Time": "19062320",

"Destination_ID1": "2"}

In the code above, the line of code which I produced for that MD5 hash specification is:

```
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(requestTextBox.Text));
```

Is this the correct way ? It seems not to be, because I get the error.
Is there any standard way in which I should do what they ask about adding MD5 hash HTTP header ?
I also tried a lot of alternatives :

```
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", bearerReqProd.GetHashCode().ToString());
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteBodyProd));
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBodyProd, 0, byteBodyProd.Length)));
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(requestTextBox.Text));
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(requestTextBox.Text + "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5(requestTextBox.Text) + "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", CreateMD5("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
bearerReqProd.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", Convert.ToBase64String(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))));
```

I know it’s an ugly way to try even what I didn’t think to be a solution… but when you don’t have any other solution and you don’t get what you need …

Thank you for any help !

Comment: The key issue is obviously dependant on what it is hashing, clearly the right combo hasnt been found yet.

Comment: JSON can contain arbitrary formatting white-space so there needs to be an agreed format for the hashes to match, try with all extraneous white-space removed?   Your best bet is to get clarification from the author/maintainer.

Comment: Does the API (web server) documentation specify from what to create hash? You create hash from payload (HTTP body).  Is this what documentation wants you to do? In that case I'd say such a mechanism adds close to zero additional protection, because anyone who is able to tamper HTTP body has also access to HTTP headers. Not to mention [all the issues with MD5 itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Overview_of_security_issues).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Now that you all have this opinion, I will ask the author to provide a more detailed explanation. But their ticketing system is with problems for some days and I will have to wait (this was a reason more for me to post this).
I also tried with all spaces/ENTERs removed but no success.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Below is code snippet that works on the system you want to integrate with ... Enjoy

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetAuthHeaderAndSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool forceTokenRefresh)
{      
  var requestContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  request.Headers.Add("X-OriginalHash", new Md5PasswordHasher().Hash(requestContent)); 
  return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);  
}

public class Md5PasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
public string Hash(string password)
{    
  return CalculateMD5Hash(password);
}

private string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
  MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
  byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
  byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));

  string result = sb.ToString();
  return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a stupid one ... this happens when 2 systems meet but you can't see details when a problem occurs.
The line is:
sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
I copied code from somebody and it was uppercase X2, instead of lowercase x2. So, the code produced all uppercase string and the server was , evidently, case sensitive, so the strings didn't match.
I can't tell you what a solution I produced: Java encryption method which was on an aspx page... the complication was very twisted.

Sorry for inconvenience and thanks for your implication!